# link_to update attribute does not give the confirmation box that i want

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a link that updates 1 attribute in the database when click. I want a confirmation box when I click this:

```
<%= link_to "Close this task", task_path(@task, task: {is_task_closed: true}), :method => :put, :confirm => "Are you sure?" , class: "btn btn-danger btn-md" %>
```

But it does not give any confirmation box. It just updates my task table. I want the user to have a prompt when this clicks to make confirmation. I tried other syntax but cant make it work. Can someone tell me what is wrong with this and why it doe not give confirmation dialog box. I have other link, ie delete link that promts dialog box when I click them. But for this update link why does it not work?

Help please thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the URI Helpers, data:{:confirm => 'Are you sure?'} should be used. You can see the reference http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

```
link_to "Visit Other Site", "http://www.rubyonrails.org/", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
# => <a href="http://www.rubyonrails.org/" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Visit Other Site</a>
```